# Create object which has keys with function type value

Tags: python

I am working in one Python program where I want to create one object like we do in JavaScript.

```js
var obj = {"sum":function(a,b){return a+b;}}`
```

Can I do a similar thing in Python?

Comment: You can, the equivalent in Python would be a lambda expression in a dictionary: `obj = {"sum": lambda a, b: a + b}`.

Comment: ``obj  = {"sum", lambda a,b : a+b} `` should do your task.

Comment: @DeepakSaini no; that's a **set**, not a dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ohh yeah typo.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways of doing this:

```
test_obj = {
  'a': 'a',
  'func': lambda: print('test')
}

test_obj['func']()
```

Or:

```
def test():
  print('test')

test_obj = {
  'a': 'a',
  'func': test
}

test_obj['func']()
```